# How to access value by key in PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

Please point me where am i wrong with my form and how to get access to $_POST data by it's key

Here are my form inputs:

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $products_in_cart; ?>['product_name']" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cart']['products'][$val['sku']]['product_name']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $products_in_cart; ?>['qty_in_cart']" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cart']['products'][$val['sku']][$qty]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $products_in_cart; ?>['price_for_item']" value="<?php echo $val['price_item']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $products_in_cart; ?>['price_for_all_items_in_cart']" value="<?php echo $price_item_total; ?>">
```

Catching data:

```
$products_in_cart = $_POST['products_in_cart'];

for ($i=0; $i < count($products_in_cart); $i++) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($products_in_cart[$i]);
    echo "</pre>";

    // !!! ISSUE: Can't access by this key
    // echo $products_in_cart[$i]['product_name'] . "<br>";
}
```

Array:

```
> [products_in_cart] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => Array
>             (
>                 ['product_name'] => Котёл на отработанном масле «EcoBoil-18/30»
>                 ['qty_in_cart'] => 1
>                 ['price_for_item'] => 35200
>                 ['price_for_all_items_in_cart'] => 35200
>             )
> 
>         [1] => Array
>             (
>                 ['product_name'] => Калорифер воздушный «HotAir-2/36»
>                 ['qty_in_cart'] => 2
>                 ['price_for_item'] => 48000
>                 ['price_for_all_items_in_cart'] => 96000
>             )
> 
>     )
```

UPD
This way works, but can't findout why i a can't gain access by key

```
foreach ($products_in_cart as $product) {
    foreach ($product as $p) {
        echo $p . "<br>";

        // This not works:
        // echo $p['product_name'] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you echo something like `$products_in_cart[1]['price_for_item'] `?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `for loop` you should use `foreach loop` like this:

```
foreach($products_in_cart as $arr) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr);
    echo "</pre>";

    // Access inner keys
    echo $arr['product_name'] . "<br>";
}
```

See more about `foreach()` from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing something like:

```
   foreach($products_in_cart as $product) {
      echo "<pre>";
      echo $product['product_name']. "<br>";
      echo $product['qty_in_cart']. "<br>";
      echo $product['price_for_item']. "<br>";
      //and so on...
      echo "</pre>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your array output at the end of your post is correct, then you have a numerically indexed array that contains associative arrays.  So you need to loop thru the numeric array, then access that particular associative array by the key.

```
<?php
// print just the product_name
for($i=0;$i<count($products_in_cart);$i++){
    print($products_in_cart[$i]['product_name']);
}

// print everything about the products_in_cart
for($i=0;$i<count($products_in_cart);$i++){
    foreach($products_in_cart[$i] as $key=>$value){
        print($key." : ".$value);
    }
}
?>
```